# DHT11 Temp/Humidity Sensor Web Service Error

Tags: php, python, mysql, web-services, wsdl

hi all i'm trying to send my temp and humidity sensor over a php.wsdl web service,
i need to parse the data over to the webservice so that i can insert it into mysql database from the webservice ..

I am encountering a few problems regarding, please advise

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from suds.client import Client

url = "http://172.20.xxx.xx``/SCS/WebService/webS.php?wsdl"
client = Client(url)



while(True):
# Run the DHT program to get the humidity and temperature readings!

    output = subprocess.check_output(["./Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "4"]);
    print output
    matches = re.search("Temp =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
    if (not matches):
    time.sleep(3)
    continue
    temp = float(matches.group(1))
# search for humidity printout
    matches = re.search("Hum =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
    if (not matches):
    time.sleep(3)
    continue
    humidity = float(matches.group(1))

    print "Temperature: %.1f C" % temp
    print "Humidity: %.1f %%" % humidity

# Append the data , including a timestamp
    try:
    values = [datetime.datetime.now(), temp, humidity]

    except:
    print "Unable to append data. Check your connection?"
    sys.exit()
```

THIS IS THE ERROR encountered

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "./websvc.py", line 13, in <module>
output = subprocess.check_output(["./Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "4"]);
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

i'm trying to use python suds from this tutorial/script from this site. please advise. 
http://bradsrpi.blogspot.sg/2013/03/raspberry-pi-soap-web-service-client.html

Comment: You should `import` the `subprocess` module if you're going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

@user1449266 is right.

you need to put

```
import subprocess
```

at the start of the file:

```
#...
import time
import subprocess
from suds.client import Client
#...
```

then the subprocess module is known under the name subprocess and when `subprocess.check_output` is written then the attribute `check_output` of subprocess is found.